# Parsable Hg log format

Tags: php, mercurial

I'm trying to parse the output of `hg log`. So far I'm just doing something simple:

```
$arg_sep = '|||';
$entry_sep = ';;;';
$log = shell_exec("hg log -l 5  --template \"{rev}$arg_sep{node}$arg_sep{author}$arg_sep{date|hgdate}$arg_sep{parents}$arg_sep{files}$arg_sep{desc}$entry_sep\"");
```

And then exploding it. I anticipate a problem with the files though. They seem to be space-separated. What if the file actually contains a space, how am I supposed to parse that?

Can I get the log in a more parsable format? JSON would be nice, but I can't seem to find anythign on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
hg log --verbose --style=xml
```

It's not quite JSON, but it is concretely parse-able and there are easy command line tools for extracting XML values.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#template-usage

You could try

```
hg log -l 5  --style xml
```

and then try to parse the resulting xml.